# URL did not return json (from remote machines only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC ASP.NET 4
when I load a page I get "The requested URL did not return json" error message.
the problem occurs when I open the webpage from a remote machine.
If I open the webpage from a browser on the server machine, it works fine without any problem.
When the problem occurs and I click on the left-bottom icon 
of the errors I get the message:
"'d' is null or no an object" in the asset.axd file.
I tried remote debugging without any luck.

thanks,
Aviad.

Comment: You need to supply more information.

Show us some code samples, and exactly what the server sends on the remote client.

Comment: Sounds like it is time to bust out The Fiddler...